# function which generate random points in polygon in c++ and postgresql

Tags: c++, postgresql, function, qt, qgis

- installing PostgreSQL database with spatial extension (POST GIS)
- create a table points (X,Y,Z) in the database
- in C # or C ++ write a program that will connect to the database
- please write a function that will generate random points within the Polish borders and save them in the table
  points (at least 1000 points, for the Z value, i.e. the height, please assume the range from 0 to 300 meters)
- please write a test that will check if the generated points are at least 3 km apart
- please create a voivodship table and import the voivodeship borders there
- please write a function that will list all generated points for each province
  are included in its outline

SHP FILES with country borders and voivodeship borders:
https://gis-support.pl/baza-wiedzy-2/dane-do-pobrania/granice-administracyjne/
Additional task:

- please draw all voivodeships and points in the program window
- please color the points in different colors for each province
- for the generated points, please perform the triangulation operation and show the result in the program window
  main

My question is how am I supposed to write this function in qt by plugin QGIS to c++ or how? I don't understand how I am supposed to do this task. Thanks in advance

I added files with Polish borders and voivodship to postgresql and created x,y,z table.
Then I connected to database via pqxx library.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <random>
#include <pqxx/stream_to.hxx>    
#include <pqxx/transaction_base.hxx>
#include <pqxx/stream_from.hxx>

int main()
{

    std::string connectionString = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password =Kotarba2020";

    try
    {
        pqxx::connection connectionObject(connectionString.c_str());
        pqxx::work worker(connectionObject);

        pqxx::result response = worker.exec("SELECT * FROM Wojewodztwa");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < response.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Id: " << response[i][0] << " X: " << response[i][1] << " Y: " << response[i][2] << " Z: " << response[i][3] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Since you have PostGIS, you can simplify your homework by calling [`ST_GeneratePoints()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html)